# ScheduledExecutorService with repeating tasks that have max duration

Tags: java, multithreading, timeout, scheduledexecutorservice

I have the following problem. I need multiple tasks to be performed simultaneously and repeatedly, each in a separate thread. Each task has its own repeat rate interval. Each task execution should take no more than a max duration (timeout) which is different for the different tasks. If a single execution exceeds that duration, it needs to be restarted. The current implementation uses a `ScheduledThreadExecutor` and `scheduleAtFixedRate(...)` method. The timeout condition is observed by creating a new thread within each task that performs the task logic and the thread is being `join`ed for the given duration, then interrupted if still alive. This is not memory efficient because it effectively doubles the number of threads for each task: one for each task in the scheduled executor and one more within each task to manage the expiration.

Another idea I have is to utilize a managing thread that constantly iterates through the tasks (the `ScheduledFuture` instances returned by the executor) and checks the current execution duration, then canceling them if needed and rescheduling. The problem with such an approach is that `ScheduledFuture` doesn't hold how long the current execution has taken. I can maintain a `Map<Future, MyTask>` and store the execution duration in the MyTask class but it already starts looking a bit too much.

Do you think there's some better solution that I can use to solve this particular problem?

Comment: Hi, what about to try with [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) and "[awaitTermination](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit))"?

Comment: Kunpapa, that won't work because awaitTermination waits for all the tasks to finish or a timeout to elapse, however in my case I have repeating tasks that need to be restarted at a certain rate, so I don't want for the Executor to be terminated, it needs to work indefinitely. It's only the single executions that will be repeated (restarted) when they finish or a timeout elapses.

Comment: As a follow up (since I had to finish my work) I implemented a variant of the second approach: we simplified the requirements, so that the timeout is same for all tasks. Then, in the main thread for this component I created a ScheduledThreadExecutor for the various tasks and then follows a while that has a sleep (for the timeout duration) and there's a for loop that iterates once through all futures, gets corresponding task from a map and then checks the actual task if still stuck (it maintains its start timestamp in nanos). Then cancels and reschedules if needed.